# Spring data mongodb search with date

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am trying to use a filter by date like below.

```
// I am using the Kotlin language
Criteria.where("date").lte(Date());
```

but instead of using the ISO format like "2015-05-16T07:55:23.257Z", spring data mongodb generate below query

```
{ "date" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : 1565820000000 }}}
```

Comment: Although following link is for spring elasticsearch data it is likely that your problem is related and the solution is the same. Mapping and Jackson serializer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042430/elasticsearch-spring-data-date-format-always-is-long

Comment: thanks Jorge. the problem is that the query is generated before I specify the class Type. mongoOperations.find(query, SpecifiedClass::class.java)

Comment: Nice that you figure it out. Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted it may help others in the future. Don't forget to add some relevant code to explain it.

Comment: sorry Jorge, but I did not solve the problem. I only pointed out the problem of your suggestion.

Comment: to be clear. I tried to set the timestamp date serialization to false in the Spring boot configurations but it didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the generated query is in BSON format, which implies that the transformation of the date to it's ISO format is done by MongoDB and not by spring